# Given that $U=100$ , $B\cap W=60$ , $n(B)=80$, and $n(W)=72$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please help me to understand set theory using an example have given above. In which, $U$ represents the total number of people, $B$ and $W$ represent those who ordered for beer and wine respectively. Calculate those who odered for
 bear only?
 wine only?
Did not order for bear and wine?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Try drawing a Venn diagram to help yourself understand how the various numbers interact with each other.

Comment: What does BnW mean?

Comment: @saulspatz I assume that represents people who ordered both beer and wine.  But I'm still trying to figure out why people would order bear.

Comment: laugh out loud. who wants to buy a bear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those who ordered only beer, you must subtract the number of those who ordered beer and wine from those who ordered beer, since for you have $B=(B-W) \cup (B\cap W)$ where $B-W$ represents those who ordered beer but didn't order wine. (Draw a Venn diagram to understand things more clearly)

[image]

So those who ordered beer only (the yellow part) are $80-60=20$

Similarly, the ones who ordered wine only are $72-60=12$

Finally to get those who ordered neither beer nor wine you do $100-(20+12+60)=100-92=8$